# Invalid number of channels in portaudio example

Tags: c, linux, audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to setup portaudio on my Raspberry Pi to build an audio manipulation device, and before getting started I am trying to run one of the example programs provided when downloading from their site (example found [here](http://www.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__read__write__wire_8c.html)), which simply listens for input and sends it to the output channel. I have downloaded and installed both ALSA and portaudio and configured ALSA based on the [tutorial](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html) and the program compiles fine, however, when I run it  I get the output:

```
Error number: -9998
Error message: Invalid number of channels
```

I have also installed and ran this example on my personal computer (running Ubuntu) following the same steps, and it runs as expected, without errors. The only differences between the Pi and my PC that I can see are that my PC has the same Default Input/Output device, while my Pi has a separate default input and output, and also my Pi is running Raspian as opposed to Ubuntu. The max inputs listed on the default input of my pi is 1 and the max outputs is 2, which I think could be the problem, but I am unsure how to change it.

One last detail, for the Raspberry Pi the input I am using is a small USB microphone, and I have not changed the default output of the Pi, which I am assuming is the 3.5 mm jack.

Comment: To set input to 1 channel try: `inputParameters.channelCount = 1;`

Comment: I set `inputParameters.channelCount = 1;` and `outputParameters.channelCount = 1;` (it didn't work if I only did one) and now it runs without errors but I can't hear any output. I think that may have to do with the default selected so I'm going to play with that a bit. Thanks for the help! :)

Edit: It appears the default output is set to the HDMI rather than the 3.5mm jack.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I only changed the constant `NUM_CHANNELS`, but the constant is not used everywhere it should.